# Update special characters to html codes in Access

Tags: html, ms-access, special-characters

I have a Access database with many columns that contain special characters (é, ä and so on). How do i use a private function like below to change these characters to html codes in multiple columns at once ?

```
Private Function EncodeString(strOriginal as string) as string
Dim strTemp as string
strTemp = strOriginal
strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ó", "&oacute;")
strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "á", "&aacute;")
---
EncodeString = strTemp
```

End Function

Answer (score 1):

You make your function `Public` instead of `Private` and use an Update query.

```sql
UPDATE myTable
SET Field1 = EncodeString([Field1]),
    Field2 = EncodeString([Field2]),
    Field77 = EncodeString([Field77])
WHERE foo = bar
```

You might consider declaring `strOriginal as Variant` so it can handle NULL values.

Comment: Thanks Andre,
What i did is :
- Made a claas-module with above code and named it "Encodestring"
- Made a update query for testing on one column : 
"UPDATE [test-snaren-klaar] SET [test-snaren-klaar].[Meta Description <meta_description> (default_fr)] = EncodeString([test-snaren-klaar]![Meta Description <meta_description> (default_fr)]);"
- If i try to run this query i get a error message : "The expression contains a undefined function EncodeString"
Can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @user5449444: You must have `Public Function EncodeString` in a standard module, not in a class module, otherwise a query can't find it.

Comment: Sorry Andre, how do i make it a standard module? Tried, but the it is not visible under Functions. Sorry... know how to create tabels and queries, but this is new to me :-)

Comment: @user5449444 You can't change a class module to standard. Create a new module and move your function there.